# Why I get the HttpErrorResponse in ionic app using restful?

Tags: php, json, angular, curl, ionic-framework

I am setting the server that return JSON, however, it is get a error after execute curl

I can get the response in chrome and postmen but fail in ionic

```
<?php
  $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
  $ch = curl_init();
  $message='vendor=mobi&username=x&sid='.session_id().'';
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://xxx);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$message);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 800);
  $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  $data=array();
  $data=array('a'=>'b');
  echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I expect the output of 'a'=>'b', but ionic got it HttpErrorResponse using data subscribe

Comment: problem in: $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';

Answer (score 0):

Should be remove

```
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie );
```

and change it to

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '');
```